# What do you mean by signed curvature??

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Can any one define "signed curvature" and explain it geometrically?

What are the difference between curvature and signed curvature?

Comment: The difference is similar to that between "concave" and "convex" for a function.  "Signed" means includes a sign that tells whether the surface is curving toward the half-space "above it" or "below it".

The general use of signs in geometry is to capture orientation.

Comment: In what context? Curves in the plane? Normal curvature of a curve on an oriented surface?

Comment: Normal curvature of a curve on an oriented surface

Comment: For future reference, I don't get pinged when I've commented to you unless you put @ with my name after it. OK, so curvature of a curve is (by convention) always nonnegative. The normal curvature is the signed curvature of the normal slice, with a $+$ when the principal normal vector of the normal slice is pointing in the direction of the surface normal, and with a $-$ when it is pointing in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, curvature is a positive number that describes how quickly a parametric curve is curving instantaneously. Signed curvature is either positive or negative, indicating that the curve is veering off to the right or the left, respectively. See this image: [image]